# Create GWT overlay for a nested JSON object

Tags: java, javascript, json, gwt, overlay

I just discovered this great site and I allow myself to bother you with the following problem:

How can you access the fields from the inner (nested) JSON object, here named "flightLegs" from the JSON object "flights"?

In order to access JSON objects from an external API (here flightstats) by a GWT application, I use the following approach:

Here is the JSON object (I recieve this correctly by the api and I can check it on the homepage too):

```
 "flights": [
{
"departureAirportFsCode": "ZRH",
"arrivalAirportFsCode": "NRT",
"departureDateFrom": "2013-01-28",
"departureDateTo": "2013-03-30",
"departureDaysOfWeek": [
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7
 ],
"arrivalDateAdjustment": 1,
"departureTime": "13:00:00.000",
"arrivalTime": "08:55:00.000",
"distanceMiles": 5969,
"flightDurationMinutes": 715,
"layoverDurationMinutes": 0,
"flightType": "NON_STOP",
"serviceType": "PASSENGER_ONLY",
"online": true,
"flightLegs": [
 {
 "departureAirportFsCode": "MUC",
 "arrivalAirportFsCode": "NRT",
 "departureTime": "13:00:00.000",
 "arrivalTime": "08:55:00.000",
 "departureDateAdjustment": 0,
 "arrivalDateAdjustment": 1,
 "arrivalTerminal": "1",
 "carrierFsCode": "LX",
 "flightNumber": "160",
 "codeshare": false,
 "equipmentCodes": [
  "343"
 ],
 "distanceMiles": 5969,
 "flightDurationMinutes": 715,
 "layoverDurationMinutes": 0
}
]
```

For example I can create Overlays for all the fields of the outer JSON object "flights" with the following code:

```
public final native String getDepartureFromAirport() /*-{
    return this.departureAirportFsCode;
}-*/;
```

This also works perfectly.

But I also need to access the Flightnumber, the field "flightnumber" from the "flightLegs" JSON object. I tried with:

```
public final native String getDepartureFromAirport() /*-{
    return this.flightLegs.flightNumber;
}-*/;
```

but this does not work, it just leaves me with an null or empty object (according to the error message).
So I'm pretty clueless how I can access the inner JSON object.

Any help would honestly be greately appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`flightLegs` is an array containing an object, so it'd be `this.flightLegs[0].flightNumber`.